# Flex rows transform into flex columns on tablets

Tags: html, css

I have stuck into responsive flex boxes.
I have 5 items in one row on desktop, I need these items to become 2 columns on tablets with respective items in each column. Moreover: 3 of 5 items will become accordions (but I achieved it through JS)

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="footer-item">
   <h3 class="mj-footer-header accordion">MENU 1</h3>
   <div class="panel">
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-item">
   <h3 class="maccordion">MENU 2</h3>
   <div class="panel">
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-item">
   <h3 class="accordion">MENU 3</h3>
   <div class="panel">
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
      <div>Menu item</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="footer-item">
   <h3>SUBSCRIBE</h3>
   <form>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
   </form>
   <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
</div>
<div class="footer-item">
   <h3>CONTACTS</h3>
   <div>Contact item</div>
   <div>Contact item</div>
   <div>Contact item</div>
   <div>Contact item</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**MY desktop CSS:**

```
.box {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

**MY tablet CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.box {

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .box>* {
      flex: 1 1 50%;
  }
}
```

But I can't achieve the final result: on tablets 1 column (50% width): MENU 1, MENU 2, MENU 3; 2 column (50% width): SUBSCRIBE, CONTACTS. So, I need two equal columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the order property and order the divs accordingly. I am attaching an example here. I have used ids for the divs for a clear idea but I would suggest using :nth-of-child() for a cleaner code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<div class="footer-item" id="test1">
                <h3 class="mj-footer-header accordion">MENU 1</h3>
                <div class="panel">
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                </div></div>

                <div class="footer-item" id="test2">
                <h3 class="maccordion">MENU 2</h3>
                <div class="panel">
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                </div></div>

                <div class="footer-item" id="test3">
                <h3 class="accordion">MENU 3</h3>
                <div class="panel">
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                <div>Menu item</div>
                </div></div>

                <div class="footer-item" id="test4">
                <h3>SUBSCRIBE</h3>
                <form>
                 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                 </form>
                 <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
                   </div>
                 <div class="footer-item" id="test5">
                    <h3>CONTACTS</h3>
                    <div>Contact item</div>
                    <div>Contact item</div>
                    <div>Contact item</div>
                    <div>Contact item</div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;
    }

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.box {

      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;


  }
  .box>* {
      flex: 1 1 50%;
  }

   #test3 {
      order:5;
    }

  #test2 {
    order:3
  }

  #test1{
    order:1;
  }

  #test4 {
    order:2;
  }

  #test5 {
    order:4;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it almost helps me, thanks, but id="test3" becomes full-width.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, everything works great, full-width only for accordion header, which I need to change as well. Thanks for your help.